# Round robin vs Demand Parallelism partitioning

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, parallelism

This is related to having a common key driver on top of the query with a nested loops, and the parallelism for the rows coming out of driver being either demand type or round robin type. I would have assumed demand partitioning would perform better but I get opposite results.

I started the queries within the same try at the same time in SQL Server. When the queries running I monitored `dm_exec_query_profiles` dmv constantly. I noticed the Round robin versions start a lot faster, they are inserting a lot more rows a lot faster into the Table Insert portion in the dmv also they pick up a lot more rows quicker from the driver side parallelism portion. Thinking logically demand partitioning should be more advantageous since our SQL server is usually over 50-60% cpu, litespeed backups running, has 64 cores etc. I was able to balance rows processed on threads a lot better with round robin partitioning but also the data within partitions are so out of balance I noticed some threads in demand partitioning only processes 1 record from the driver whereas the average records from the driver is around 196. With the demand partitioning I order the rows within partitions descending vs in round robin I try to balance the rows better.

Should I always use round robin instead, why does round robin starts processing rows a lot faster than demand partitioning, can I do more optimization for demand partitioning?

The query plans are in the One Drive link, I couldn't find another way of posting them here (pastetheplan only accepts xml, which does not capture the extra information like wait stats & duration captured by Plan Explorer).

---

> CompareRoundRobinToDemand_DM_2_5114.pesession
>    CompareRoundRobinToDemand_RRB_2_3046.pesession

started at the same time, Round Robin was considerably faster

---

> CompareRoundRobinToDemand_DM_3_5228.pesession
>    CompareRoundRobinToDemand_RRB_3_4367.pesession

started at the same time, Round Robin was faster again

---

> CompareRoundRobinToDemand_DM_4_4813.pesession
>    CompareRoundRobinToDemand_RRB_4_3577.pesession

started at the same time, Round Robin was faster again

Thank you in advance.

[image: Monitoring Running Sessions]
[Query Plans](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Apv4g3d243EpiNBpPoJIUooBJK7vNg)

[image: SQL Server Version and running Traces]

I am able to balance round robin rows almost perfect whereas for demand I just order the driver in rows descending order, balancing the rows in demand is an option in my procedure but did not produce better results. In my observation demand performs better when overall CPU usage is less and Round robin performs better when server is busier. I noticed demand creates one extra thread compared to round robin and also overall cpu utilization in demand is slightly higher than similar RRB version.

i am aware of imbalance of row distribution in demand. the memory grant is also on purpose, it's not using that much memory at the end. the first 16 records passed from driver is the same in demand vs round robin, but round robin starts processing them a lot faster for some reason. I want to understand why. I also want to understand when it's more beneficial to use demand or round robin. It seems like when server is idle demand works faster and when server has existing load round robin is faster, thats an observation so far, does that have a basis I dont know.

Answer (score 8):

> Should I always use round robin instead

Only if you find it produces "better" results for your particular workload, or for particular queries within that workload.

In general, I would say no.  My personal experience is that Demand (D) partitioning tends to have fewer problems than Round Robin (RR). The particular plan you shared does not seem to have any of the more common features that can cause performance problems with RR, but it is tough to assess at a distance.

> why does round robin starts processing rows a lot faster than demand partitioning

If I were to hazard a guess, I would say the D partitioning threads are checking and yielding the processor more frequently. A thread that uses less of its quantum on average (by checking and yielding more often) is a good scheduling citizen, but it may be [punished for that good behaviour](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/04/01/sql-2016-it-just-runs-faster-updated-scheduling-algorithms/) (before SQL Server 2016). The screenshot you shared does seem to show the D plan getting less CPU time than the concurrent RR execution.

D pulls single rows across the exchange whereas RR pushes whole packets - and yield checks occur at exchanges (among many other places). A very detailed analysis would be required to confirm this (or any other) theory.

> can I do more optimization for demand partitioning?

The plan seems reasonable enough from what I can see.

It is interesting that the screenshot shows a merge join whereas the uploaded plans all use hash join. Trying a co-located merge join was one of the first suggestions that came to mind - as explained in my article [Improving Partitioned Table Join Performance](https://www.sql.kiwi/2013/06/improving-partitioned-table-join-performance.html).

You could also check on thread distribution across schedulers and perhaps experiment with different [thread placement strategies](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2016/03/04/sql-server-parallel-query-placement-decision-logic/). I would certainly be checking that the D plan was allocating threads as optimally as the RR version (e.g. no concurrent same-branch threads sharing the same scheduler).

Perhaps also look at presenting the demand rows in a different order. What you have now may be based on a sensible expectation, but that's not to say it is necessarily optimal.

In any case, I would be very wary of drawing general conclusions about D vs RR based on this one example.

---

> I noticed demand creates one extra thread compared to round robin

This is an illusion due to a timing difference. In the RR plan, the Index Scan completes very quickly, with its rows stuffed into packets on the exchange. The thread running the scan thus terminates quickly.

In the D plan, individual rows are pulled on demand across the exchange and fully processed before a new row is pulled across. So, the Constant Scan thread hangs around for longer.

Both plans have two concurrent branches, with DOP (16) threads reserved for each. Both use 17 threads as reported in the `ThreadStat` showplan element (16 for the main branch, 1 for the serial index scan/constant scan).

Answer (score 6):

> Thinking logically demand partitioning should be more advantageous
>   since our SQL server is usually over 50-60% cpu, litespeed backups
>   running, has 64 cores etc.

I can't quite follow you here. Perhaps you think that demand distribution will be more efficient due to a possibility that one of the threads will get "stuck" if you're using round robin partitioning? On busy servers your threads will do small pieces of work as they're able to do so. If you have 64 cores and the server uses around 60% CPU doesn't that mean that you have more than enough headroom for round robin partitioning on 16 threads to work well?

Here's the row distribution for the round robin plan (CompareRoundRobinToDemand_DM_2_5114.psession) at the sequence project:

[image: round robin]

All of the operators have pretty even row distributions. This is a good thing if you're trying to optimize your query to take as little time as possible and none of the threads end up on a completely overloaded scheduler. If one thread is assigned too many rows then the query may end up waiting on that final thread to finish its work.

Here's the row distribution for the demand query (CompareRoundRobinToDemand_DM_2_5114.pesession):

[image: demand]

Some of your threads process 8X as many rows as the others. That's not what you want to see if you need your query to finish as quickly as possible. That doesn't mean that this outcome isn't better than round robin partitioning depending on the server workload, but it seems as if you didn't benefit from demand distribution in this case.

On an unrelated note, I would be mindful of this warning:

> The query memory grant detected "ExcessiveGrant", which may impact the reliability. Grant size: Initial 288185664 KB, Final 288185664 KB, Used 9726112 KB.

When those two queries run you're forcing SQL Server to dedicate 576 GB of memory with most of it not being used. On a very busy server that could cause problems for other processes.